# +2 at a rep cost

Tags: feature-request, reputation, up-votes

Sometimes I like an item so much that I would be willing to give it more exposure with extra upvotes as the expense of personal reputation points (SE currency).

Has such a feature ever been considered? If so, what subtlety or exploitation have I missed to explain why it was rejected?

NB: This is not about bounties - I am aware that additional exposure could be achieved using bounties - I am talking about *1* addition up-vote.

Comment: @Cowards What is _wrong_ with this question? Why is it unsuitable for SE?

Comment: Voting on meta means people don't agree with your feature request, not that there's anything wrong with the question itself.

Comment: @PeterJ So, people should only suggest things people will approve of? Discussion can be useful to understand and develop the system better... But if you make a suggestion or open a discussion about something people don't want added into the system you can have your rep stripped away into oblivion!

Comment: No not really, remember the rep is only here not on SO. There is a plan to give SO it's own specific meta that will be like all the other site-specific meta sites in the network where rep changes don't count at all.

Comment: @d'alar'cop _"give it more exposure with extra upvotes"_ - I'm confused. Exposure means people seeing something. Upvotes don't _ever_ give exposure, just points and reputation. What are you referring to?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Anonymous downvoters are not cowards. Downvotes already have implicit meaning: the question is unclear, does not show research effort or, in the case of meta, someone disagrees with you. If your reason is only those things, there may not be much worthwhile saying.

Comment: I do have a response to this, but as I'm about to be visiting someone it will have to come later!

Comment: I'm sure this question is a duplicate of one I asked a while back, but I can't seem to find it; it may be deleted.

Comment: @MrLister Did that question receive such a negative response as well?

Comment: @MrLister Maybe you can also offer some insight into being forced to lose MetaRep (depriving me of privileges) while people continue to downvote a legitimate suggestion (which cannot be deleted because it has answers)

Comment: @d'alar'cop Yeah, my question was downvoted as well. Downvoting here just means people disagree with you. That's something you'll have to live with. Rep in this place doesn't indicate how good or bad you are in your chosen field, but how many people you can get to agree with your posts.

Comment: You seem to be way too worried about rep. It's just a bunch of imaginary internet points.

Comment: @MrLister If you did ask about it, it wasn't on this Meta.

Comment: @GraceNote It was actually, but possibly with a different user account, that has since been merged or removed. Anyway, since it was deleted, I don't think this is worth spending effort to find on.

Comment: @PeterJ The catch is that downvotes on main meta cost rep, whereas downvotes on site metas don't. So you lose out by posting a feature request people disagree with on main meta.

Comment: People are still downvoting this :D Get a life people

Answer (score 13):

There is a feature named [Bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)! If you think the answerer deserves more reputation for the answer, instead of additional upvotes you can give him/her your own reputation by starting a bounty.

If you are talking about multiple voting on a post, I disagree with this as it doesn't make any sense. If we allow this we won't be able to determine the exact quality of the post.

Comment: Yes, I know - but this is not about bounties. This is about giving a single extra upvote.

Comment: @d'alar'cop if you want to give them extra reputation, and you're willing to do it at the expense of your own reputation, that's _exactly_ what the bounty feature is about.

Answer (score 8):

I think this feature is unnecessary.  It adds complexity where none is needed.  By allowing a "double upvote" you degrade a single upvote.

Additionally, don't forget about the **favorite button**!